# Why did each Pandava fall during Svargarohani?

Tags: mahabharata

In final Mahabharata Mahaprasthanika Parva, during Svargarohani (ascent to heaven), 5 Pandavas and Draupadi take the long trek beyond Badrinath in Uttarakhand beyond Mana village (Satopanth marg exists even today).

Each Pandava drops dead one by one in a particular order - all except Yudhishtir (and a dog which was following them), who ascends to heaven.

What was the reason given by Yudhishtir when each one fell - what sins had they committed for their downfall ?

Comment: Dead is change of state eventually everyone meet in heaven Manysha deha is not suitable in higher realms for that matter even hell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is what happened](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m17/m17002.htm) :

**1. Fall of Draupadi**

> As those mighty ones were proceeding quickly, all rapt in Yoga,
> **Yajnaseni**, falling of from Yoga, dropped down on the Earth. Beholding her fallen down, Bhimasena of great strength addressed king
> Yudhishthira the just, saying, ‘O scorcher of foes, this princess
> never did any sinful act. Tell us what the cause is for which Krishna
> has fallen down on the Earth!’
>
> "Yudhishthira said: ‘O best of men, though we were all equal unto her
> she had great partiality for Dhananjaya. She obtains the fruit of that
> conduct today, O best of men.’"

---

**2. Fall of Sahadeva**

> Then Sahadeva of great learning fell down on the Earth. Beholding him
> drop down, Bhima addressed the king, saying, ‘He who with great
> humility used to serve us all, alas, why is that son of Madravati
> fallen down on the Earth?’
>
> "Yudhishthira said, ‘He never thought anybody his equal in wisdom. It
> is for that fault that this prince has fallen down.’

---

**3. Fall of Nakula**

> Beholding both Krishna and the Pandava Sahadeva fallen down, the brave
> Nakula, whose love for kinsmen was very great, fell down himself. Upon
> the falling down of the heroic Nakula of great personal beauty, Bhima
> once more addressed the king, saying, ‘This brother of ours who was
> endued with righteousness without incompleteness, and who always
> obeyed our behests, this Nakula who was unrivalled for beauty, has
> fallen down.’
>
> "Thus addressed by Bhimasena, Yudhishthira, said, with respect to
> Nakula, these words: ‘He was of righteous soul and the foremost of all
> persons endued with intelligence. He, however, thought that there was
> nobody that equalled him in beauty of person. Indeed, he regarded
> himself as superior to all in that respect. It is for this that Nakula
> has fallen down. Know this, O Vrikodara. What has been ordained for a
> person, O hero, must have to be endured by him.’

---

**4. Fall of Arjuna**

> Beholding Nakula and the others fall down, Pandu’s son Arjuna of white
> steeds, that slayer of hostile heroes, fell down in great grief of
> heart. When that foremost of men, who was endued with the energy of
> Shakra, had fallen down, indeed, when that invincible hero was on the
> point of death, Bhima said unto the king, ‘I do not recollect any
> untruth uttered by this high-souled one. Indeed, not even in jest did
> he say anything false. What then is that for whose evil consequence
> this one has fallen down on the Earth?’
>
> "Yudhishthira said, ‘Arjuna had said that he would consume all our
> foes in a single day. Proud of his heroism, he did not, however,
> accomplish what he had said. Hence has he fallen down. This Phalguna
> disregarded all wielders of bows. One desirous of prosperity should
> never indulge in such sentiments.’"

---

**5. Fall of Bhima**

> Then Bhima fell down. Having fallen down, Bhima addressed king
> Yudhishthira the just, saying, ‘O king, behold, I who am thy darling
> have fallen down. For what reason have I dropped down? Tell me if thou
> knowest it.’
>
> "Yudhishthira said, ‘Thou wert a great eater, and thou didst use to
> boast of thy strength. Thou never didst attend, O Bhima, to the wants
> of others while eating. It is for that, O Bhima, that thou hast fallen
> down.’

Comment: Please try to improve the answer. Add short information above each one if possible. I mean, for improving readability.

Comment: What improvement are you expecting?  The OP asked for the reasons given by Yudhishthir at the fall of each member and I had provided the same

Comment: Answer is correct and fine. But some text you can add on your own so that one can read the exact reason without even going to the scriptural statements.